# batch file for copying files from one place to another

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I program a bat file that would be capable of putting `file.dll` that is in the same folder that a `.bat` file is in into the `windowsMainDir/system32` folder but only if the file does not already exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your batch file like "copy_file.cmd" and put in these contents:

```
@echo off
SET SRC="%~dp0file.dll"
SET DEST="%WINDIR%\system32\file.dll"
if not exist %DEST% copy /V %SRC% %DEST%
```

If the destination file does not exist, it will copy the source file to the destination.  The `/V` switch makes copy verify that the file was copied correctly, and is optional.

The `%~dp0` in `SRC` takes the drive `d` and path `p` from the variable `%0` (the batch file's path) and uses that path as a prefix to `file.dll`.  You want do do this to guarantee that the script always takes the file from the same directory as the batch file, and not the current directory.  E.g., if your batch file was on a network drive mapped to `H:`, you could still run it from `C:`.

```
c:\> h:\shared_scripts\copy_file.cmd
```

Comment: I guess on a modern file system you can safely ignore the `/V` switch.

Comment: You may want to change the 2nd line to `SET SRC="%~dp0file.dll"`.  `%~dp0` expands to the path of the folder the batch file is in.  That way, if the current directory is not the same as the one the batch file is in, you'll still take the correct file.

Comment: @Cheran S:  Great idea, and I've made the change.